# Referencing value of an array based on the values of another

Tags: matlab

I have an array d = [0,1000,2000]. Based on this array, I compute the value of another array, let's say J = [0,5000,8000], where J = 3*d+2000.
Now, during iteration using a for loop, if d=0, I want to extract value of J(1); if d = 1000, then I want to extract values of J(1) and J(2); if d = 2000, I want to extract values of J(1),J(2) and J(3). What would be a generic way to cross-reference values of two arrays?

Comment: Could you share some of your code with us to show what you've tried?

Comment: J != 3 * D + 2000

Comment: Iterate over both in lockstep?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your values in `d` are unique and the length of `d` and `J` are identical, use MATLAB's [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) function, especially using [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html#d117e416624) version with `n = 1`, and `direction = 'first'`, like so:

```matlab
idx = find(d == ii, 1, 'first')
```

Here, `ii` is the desired value, e.g. `0`, `1000`, and so on. You'll get the index of the (first) occurrence of the desired value in `d`. Then, just extract all values from `J` from `1` to `idx`:

```matlab
J(1:idx)
```

Here's a small test script:

```matlab
d = [0, 1000, 2000]
J = 3 * d + 2000

% If your counter variable only contains valid values from d
for ii = d
  idx = find(d == ii, 1, 'first');
  printf('d = %d\n', ii);
  printf('Extracted values are: ');
  printf('%d ', J(1:idx));
  printf('\n \n');  
end

% If your counter variable may contain any value
for ii = 0:2000
  idx = find(d == ii, 1, 'first');
  if (~isempty(idx))
    printf('d = %d\n', ii);
    printf('Extracted values are: ');
    printf('%d ', J(1:idx));
    printf('\n \n');  
  end
end
```

And, the output looks like this:

```matlab
d =
      0   1000   2000

J =
   2000   5000   8000

d = 0
Extracted values are: 2000

d = 1000
Extracted values are: 2000 5000

d = 2000
Extracted values are: 2000 5000 8000

d = 0
Extracted values are: 2000

d = 1000
Extracted values are: 2000 5000

d = 2000
Extracted values are: 2000 5000 8000
```

Hope that helps!

P.S. I haven't thought about vectorization here, since the question states, that a for loop is used in any case.